# Why the info displayed on my console after executed mail command?

Tags: email

I have installed and  set the sendmail .

```
root@localhost:~# echo "Just testing my email " | mail -s "Sendmail gmail  " test@qq.com
```

The info displayed on my console after the command be executed.

```
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

Why the info displayed?Can i disable it on my console after email command been executed?

I  send a email to others ,not other email was sent to me ,the info `You have new mail in /var/mail/root` can't express the situation properly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you (`root` on the local system) got a mail as it showed.  It's delivered (appended to a file `/var/mail/root`) by local mailer daemon (sendmail, postfix, etc), probably notifying you of mailer configuration error, or your last mail got bounced (failed to deliver it to the finail recipient `test@qq.com`).

You can read each mail interactively by running `mail` without arguments.

Printing the message `You have new mail` is done by your shell.  You can disable it by `unset MAILCHECK` on bash.

Comment: no error at all ,i open my email box ,there is a email sent to me.

Comment: Anyway `root` on your system got new mails in `/var/mail/root`, just run `mail` and see what they say.